# How to select all values matching a key in an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working in Typescript.

If I have an object about which I know nothing, how could I obtain
from that object a list of all the fields which have the name of, say,
"speed". (Clearly the answer would be null if there were no such entries).

I could JSON.stringify and write my own parsing, but was wondering if there was another way.

So, for example, my object might be:

```
MyObject = {AnEntry:{"speed":"5", "somthingElse":6},
AnotherEntry:{"somethingElse":"3"},
YetAnother:true,
AndMore:{"speed":"eleven"},
Finally:{"more":7,nested:{"notHere":7, "speed":"5"}}};
```

So, in this case, I would like query MyObject and return [5,"eleven",5]

I've EDITED: Add = sign and updated object to show that I want to be able to cope with possibly nested objects.

Comment: Best way (IMO) would be to use Object `reduce`. This is an Array function, but there is an implementation of Object `reduce` you can find on SO

Comment: PS: You have a typo `Finally:{"speed"5"}` - should be `Finally:{"speed":"5"}`

Comment: Updated example and fixed typos thanks.

Comment: You should update the expected return value to match your updated example.  I presume you want it to return `["5", "eleven", "5"]` now?

Comment: Yes, Just noticed. Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know nothing about the object, the "speed" attributes might be nested at multiple depths within your object.  You can use recursion to traverse the tree of nested children to reach all of them.

```
const MyObject = {
  speed: "1",
  AnEntry: {"speed": "2","somthingElse": 6},
  AnotherEntry: {"somethingElse": {"speed":"3"}},
  YetAnother: true,
  AndMore: {"speed": "four"},
  Finally: {"speed": 5}
};

let speeds=[];
function buildSpeeds(speeds, obj) {
    for (key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (!Object.hasOwn(obj, key)) continue;
        let value=obj[key];
        if (key=="speed") speeds.push(value);
        if (value!==null && typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)) {
            buildSpeeds(speeds, value);
        }
    }
}
buildSpeeds(speeds, MyObject);
console.log(JSON.stringify(speeds));
```

Result:

```
["1","2","3","four",5]
```

Answer (score 1):

**After your Edit**

To get nested *prop* *"speed"* values, use a recursive function like:

```js
const MyObject = {
  AnEntry:{"speed":"5", "somthingElse":6},
  AnotherEntry:{"somethingElse":"3"},
  YetAnother:true,
  AndMore:{"speed":"eleven"},
  Finally:{"more":7, nested:{"notHere":7, "speed":"5"}}
};

const getValues = (obj, prop) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  if (typeof v === "object") a.push(...getValues(v, prop));
  else if (k === prop) a.push(v);
  return a;
}, []);


const res = getValues(MyObject, "speed");
console.log(res);
```

to get a unique set of values, reduce into a `new Set`:

```js
const MyObject = {
  AnEntry:{"speed":"5", "somthingElse":6},
  AnotherEntry:{"somethingElse":"3"},
  YetAnother:true,
  AndMore:{"speed":"eleven"},
  Finally:{"more":7, nested:{"notHere":7, "speed":"5"}}
};

const getValues = (obj, prop) => [...Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  if (typeof v === "object" && Object.hasOwn(v, prop)) a.add(...getValues(v, prop));
  else if (k === prop) a.add(v);
  return a;
}, new Set)];


const res = getValues(MyObject, "speed");
console.log(res);
```

---

To get an array of the filtered fields where `speed` property (key) exists you could use:

```js
const MyObject = {
  AnEntry: {"speed": "5","somthingElse": 6},
  AnotherEntry: {"somethingElse": "3"},
  YetAnother: true,
  AndMore: {"speed": "eleven"},
  Finally: {"speed": "5"}
};

const fields = Object.values(MyObject).filter((ob) => Object.hasOwn(ob, "speed"));
console.log(fields);
```

To get only an Array of the values use:

```js
const MyObject = {
  AnEntry: {"speed": "5","somthingElse": 6},
  AnotherEntry: {"somethingElse": "3"},
  YetAnother: true,
  AndMore: {"speed": "eleven"},
  Finally: {"speed": "5"}
};

const values = Object.values(MyObject).reduce((a, ob) => (Object.hasOwn(ob, "speed") && a.push(ob.speed), a), []);
console.log(values);
```

To get only unique values, use `new Set()`

```js
const MyObject = {
  AnEntry: {"speed": "5","somthingElse": 6},
  AnotherEntry: {"somethingElse": "3"},
  YetAnother: true,
  AndMore: {"speed": "eleven"},
  Finally: {"speed": "5"}
};

const valuesUnique = [...Object.values(MyObject).reduce((a, ob) => (Object.hasOwn(ob, "speed") && a.add(ob.speed), a), new Set())];
console.log(valuesUnique);
```

Docs:

- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Object.hasOwn()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)
- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Set() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set)

Answer (score 0):

```
const data =  {
  AnEntry: { speed: "5", somthingElse: 6 },
  AnotherEntry: { somethingElse: "3" },
  YetAnother: true,
  AndMore: {
    OtherInfo: { speed: "eleven", method: "dsf" },
    detailInfo: {
      infoTest: {
        speed: 123123,
        k: "fff",
      },
    },
  },
  Finally: { speed: 0 },
}

const getField = (object = {}, field = "") => {
  let keys = Object.keys(object);
  keys = keys.length == 1 && object[keys[0]] == object ? [] : keys;
  let list = [];
  if (keys.indexOf(field) != -1) {
    list.push(object[field]);
    object[field] = {};
  }
  if (keys.length != 0)
    list = [
      ...list,
      ...keys
        .map((key) => [...getField(object[key], field)])
        .reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, ...cur]),
    ];
  return list.filter(
    (item) => !(typeof item == "object" && item.length == 0)
  );
};

  getField(data, "speed") // ['5', 'eleven', 123123, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks to all for your help. Very much appreciated.